# setCreatedAt Is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, product, review, date, product-review

From the following script below, I dynamically add evaluations on the products, however I am not able to set the creation date from `$review->setCreatedAt($data_avaliacao);`. I already researched the subject, I saw several types of suggestions, but none with success. Thanks in advance!

```
while($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        if (($array['sugestao_nps'] != "") && ($array['sugestao_nps'] != NULL) && ($array['score_nps'] >= 7)) {
            $product_sku = $array['SKU'];
            $product_id = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getIdBySku($product_sku);
            $nome_cliente = utf8_encode($array['nome_cliente']);
            $data_avaliacao = strtotime($array['data_nps']." ".Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate('H:i:s'));
            echo $array['score_nps']." - ".$nome_cliente." - ".$product_id." - ".$array['order_id']." - ".$data_avaliacao." - ".utf8_encode($array['sugestao_nps'])."<br />";
            if (($array['score_nps'] == 10) || ($array['score_nps'] == 9)) {
                $rating_id = 3;
                $rating_value = 15;
            } else if(($array['score_nps'] == 8) || ($array['score_nps'] == 7)){
                $rating_id = 3;
                $rating_value = 14;
            }
            $review = Mage::getModel('review/review');
            $review->setEntityPkValue($product_id);//product id
            $review->setStatusId(1);
            $review->setDetail(utf8_encode($array['sugestao_nps']));
            $review->setEntityId(1);                                      
            $review->setStoreId(0); 
            $review->setTitle("");           
            $review->setStatusId(1); //approved
            $review->setCustomerId(null);
            $review->setNickname($nome_cliente);
            $review->setCreatedAt($data_avaliacao);
            $review->setReviewId($review->getId());
            $review->setStores(array(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()));
            $review->save();
            Mage::getModel('rating/rating')
                ->setRatingId($rating_id)
                ->setReviewId($review->getId())
                ->addOptionVote($rating_value,$product_id);
            $review->aggregate();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`created_at`should be in this format : `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Comment: But it's in that format. From `$array['data_nps']` I get the date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format and from `Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate('H:i:s')` I get the time in the `HH:MM:SS` format.

Comment: When you `var_dump($data_avaliacao)` you get this format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` ? try it please

Comment: Giving a `var_dump($data_value);` maintaining the current code, with the conversion to type time being: `$data_avaliacao = strtotime($array['data_nps']." ".Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate ('H:i:s'));` I have the following return, for example: `int(1508772326)`. Removing the conversion to the type time being the code `$data_avaliacao = $array['data_nps']." ".Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate('H:i:s');` I have the following return, for example: `string(19) "2017-10-23 13:27:40"`

Comment: Because the field in the database is of type `timestamp`, I do this conversion.

Comment: Of course, the attribute is of type  `timestamp`